# Excel VBA Stopwatch breaking at midnight

Tags: excel, vba, timer, stopwatch

I have a worksheet which I use to track progress recording audiobooks (I'm a narrator). On each sheet, I have a timer that I use to track how many hours I record each day/session.

If the timer is running at midnight, it sets the timer to 20:00:00 and keeps going. I often am recording at midnight, so this is a major issue if I don't remember to stop the timer before midnight and restart it after.

Here is a link to the whole Excel file. You can find the timer in the TEMPLATE worksheet. The Macros for the timer are within Module1.

http://recording-tracker.narratedby.me

Here is all the code:

```
    Option Explicit

Dim NextTick As Date, t As Date, PreviousTimerValue As Date, strSheetName As String, lRowTime As Long, lRowDate As Date, CurrentTimerValue As Date, StartTimerValue As Date


Sub StartTime()
strSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

StartTimerValue = PreviousTimerValue
CurrentTimerValue = PreviousTimerValue
t = Time
Call ExcelstrSheetName
End Sub

Private Sub ExcelstrSheetName()

strSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName).Range("Q1").Value = Format(Time - t + PreviousTimerValue, "hh:mm:ss")

NextTick = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

Application.OnTime NextTick, "ExcelstrSheetName"

End Sub

Sub StopClock()

strSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

On Error Resume Next

Application.OnTime earliesttime:=NextTick, procedure:="ExcelstrSheetName", schedule:=False

CurrentTimerValue = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName).Range("Q1").Value

End Sub

Sub Reset()

strSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

CurrentTimerValue = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName).Range("Q1").Value
On Error Resume Next

Application.OnTime earliesttime:=NextTick, procedure:="ExcelstrSheetName", schedule:=False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName).Range("Q1").Value = 0

End Sub
```

The cell Q1 is what holds the timer value at any given time.

I have removed other Subs and portions of these Subs which are irrelevant to my question. This is the basic stopwatch function.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to lead anywhere. It's difficult to reason about your code without knowing the function of the various ranges you refer to in your code.  Also, your code would be easier to follow if your global `strSheetName` was instead a worksheet object like `ws` for example. Then you can replace those many instances of  `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)` with `ws` and your code becomes twice as easy to read.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have used https...

http://recording-tracker.narratedby.me

Comment: And most of this code was taken from someone else's code which I just tweaked for my own purposes. I am not a skilled coder, just a tweaker, so thank you for the tips on cleaning it up!

Comment: I have also now removed some Subs that were extra functionality, as well as some parts of these Subs which facilitated those. This is now just the stopwatch functionality. Hopefully, that makes it easier to read and diagnose.

Comment: `t = Time` looks like part of the problem - `Time` has no date component, only a time value: comparing two `Time` values from different days will not give a useful timespan.  You should use `Now` instead, since it returns both date and time.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks, Tim. I'd seen some stuff about that on my searches. Sorry to be a pain, but not really being a programmer and just a tweaker, might you be able to show me how this code would be changed to incorporate that? I really appreciate your looking at this.

Comment: Just change `Time` to `Now`